# How to write php code inside jquery to update database table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working in Banking project .I want to write php code to update table upon successful Transaction using ajax . suppose i am sending request from **fundtransfer.php** to external API and the External API is also responding correctly .Now upon successful API respond i want to update my database table field name **status** from pending to completed .

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
            url:"http://someexternalwebsite.com/API",
            type:"post",
            data:"variable="+value,
            success:function(result)
            {
                if(result==100)
                {
                    $("#message").html(successful transaction);
                    //Now i want to update my database tabale status saying Successful Transation 
                    //where to write these all php mysql code to update my database table
                   // without loading and redirecting page
                }   

                else
                {
                    $("#message").html(some thing gone wrong);
                }

            }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: `Same-origin-policy` won't allow you to make an ajax request to another server.

Comment: In the response form the API you would need to send another AJAX request to your PHP server-side code.  In that code you'd interact with the database like you would in any other PHP code.

Comment: You mean i have to write another <script> tag below this <script> tag @David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without loading and redirecting page

The same thing you're doing now... Making an AJAX request.  (Assuming your initial AJAX request isn't rejected by the Same Origin Policy...)  Upon successfully returning from the first AJAX request, you'd make a second one to your code.  Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'someAPI',
    success: function (response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'someDBPage',
            success : function (dbResponse) {
                // notify the user of success
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The PHP code at `someDBPage` would interact with your database just like any other PHP code.  And you'd send it data just like any other AJAX POST request, similar to how you're sending data to the API URL now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:
$.get("http://someexternalwebsite.com/API/?variable="+value) for the http GET method.
or:
Use JavaScript:

```
         function post(data, url){
            $.post(url , data
            , function (response) {
                func(response);
            }); 
}
```

Then use post(....) inside jquery
I hope it helps you, Good luck :)